# How do I set secure `_cfuid` cookies in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ssl, cookies, cloudflare

how do I enable the secure flag for the `_cfuid` cookie in Rails 5?

I've already added `config.force_ssl = true` in `production.rb`, my app is served with a valid `ssl` certificate from Heroku, and the Mozilla Observatory gives my app a security score of 'A'

But when I try checking out the site in Postman I get this:

[image: POSTMAN shows the secure flag is set to "false"]

Comment: Are you using `session` or some other type of cookie?

Comment: @ollpu, pretty much a standard site, except I'm using devise for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cookie is set by CloudFlare and has nothing to do with rails:

Read about the cookie [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170156-What-does-the-CloudFlare-cfduid-cookie-do-). Updating the question to clarify.